# flexslider keyboard option not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flexslider

I am trying to load flexslider using angular but the thing is I can't get the keyboard option to work.Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong

```
$scope.loadFlexSlider = function(){
    debugger;
    console.log("loadBxSlider");
    angular.element('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

    angular.element('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel",
    keyboard: true
  });
```

**UPDATE**

Is there any way to control the keyboard movement manually

Comment: what is your version of the slider? in its docs, you can find this note: keyboard - Previously called "keyboardNav" in v1.8 and below.

Comment: @drys it version is 2.5.0

Answer (score 2):

Since you're syncing with thumbnails I believe you need to add multipleKeyboard: true. I have added it at the end of your code:

```
$scope.loadFlexSlider = function(){
    debugger;
    console.log("loadBxSlider");
    angular.element('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

    angular.element('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel",
    keyboard: true,
    multipleKeyboard: true
  });
```